# Is there any significance to naming the DynamicDictionary parameter in NancyFX?

Tags: nancy

The [documentation for NancyFX](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#pattern-scoring) seems to switch between giving the DynamicDictionary a full name (`parameters`) and just using underscore (`_`)

```
Get["/hello/{name}"] = parameters => {
    return "Hello " + parameters.name;
};
```

vs

```
Get["/products/{id}"] = _ => {
    //do something
};
```

Is there any significance to the naming of this parameter? The underscore appears to be a NancyFX convention but one that's applied inconsistently even within the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no enforced significance to that naming. The convention is that parameters called `_` are not used, whereas parameters with "real" name are.

Comment: A convention even the Nancy docs violate ;) So don't consider it gospel that you need to adhere to it - use whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @moo totally agree. It's just a guide line used a lot in and around Nancy

Comment: There isn't an actual convention. I for one name everything _ regardless if its used or not. For consistency. If I decided to make use of a value then I don't want to go change the naming to paramaters just because im now using it.